# Redshift scanning/returning more rows than needed by limit clause

Tags: amazon-redshift

The Redshift console shows that Redshift is scanning/returning more rows than needed by limit clause (note: My SQL client is receiving the expected number of rows).  Also, Redshift is estimating a full seq scan. I'm assuming this excessive scan/return is slowing down the response to my SQL client.  Why is redshift doing this, and how can I prevent it in order to increase query response?

Here, I `limit 1` but 80 rows are scanned/returned:
[image]

Here, I `limit 1000000` but 40000040 rows are scanned/returned:
[image]

Here, I `select top 1000 *` but 40040 rows are scanned/returned:
[image]

These queries are running against a 20-node cluster.

Comment: One thing I suggest here, use specific column rather `*`

Comment: Thanks @RedBoy, but I need every column.

Comment: From where is that screenshot coming? Is it the Redshift console or your SQL client? Does it happen if you say `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: please post your full sql

Comment: @JonScott: `select * from <table> limit 2500000;` (i'm benchmarking)

i also tried `select top 2500000 * from <table>;`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, the screenshot is from the Redshift console.  My SQL client received the expected number of rows.  I've played around with the limit/top numbers, and it seems that ~40x the number request are scanned/returned (please see the updates to my question).

Comment: Oh! You're showing a picture from the EXPLAIN plan. Yes, it has to go through all rows to construct the response. The LIMIT is applied at the end of the query. The number of rows returned to your client should match the LIMIT clause.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, but it isn't going through all rows, just ~40x more than included in the LIMIT.

I was expecting compute nodes to be smart and return no more rows than needed by the LIMIT, so maybe I'd see (num compute nodes * LIMIT num) returned, but I'm seeing even more than that.

Answer (score -1):

This is Redshift feature when you use limit it first scan all the data and then put limit of it.

TO solve your problem use **top ***

Example below:

THe query **select * from tablename limit 123456;** can be written as **select top 123456 * from tablename;**

Let me know for further help required in Redshift.

Comment: same as before: it returned many times the number of rows i needed to the leader node

Comment: `TOP` and `LIMIT` are functionally equivalent, so it doesn't matter which is used - the result will be  identical.